# ASP.NET Details View - Editing into Null Value Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling, null, detailsview

I am using ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2010.

I have a website that features a shopping cart, the user can signup which has validation using the RequiredFieldValidator control meaning they must enter something for certain fields e.g. Address 1 / E-Mail. This is also tied to a Database which for these fields does not allow null values.

My issue that is after logging in, adding items to cart, quantities etc, I have a confirmation order page - similar to most online shopping websites were the shopping basket is displayed along with the user's Customer Details, which is shown through a DetailsView, connected to a SqlDataSource which is running a query that just displays their shipping details as previously entered.

However, if I say select Edit, which is using the DetailsView's own property and change the Address1 line to nothing, the DetailsView sends it as null value after accepting and as a result the whole thing crashes.

I have tried examples like:

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewPageEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.PageIndexChanging
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = "Please verify changes made to Customer Details."
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemUpdating

    Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = "Please verify changes made to Customer Details."

    End Try
End Sub
Protected Sub detailsView1_ItemUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemUpdating

    Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = "Please verify changes made to Customer Details."

    End Try
End Sub
```

So basically `Try` / `Catch` statements which has worked for everything else. But because I can't get access to any proper code behind for the DetailsView since it's just taken from Visual Studio I'm stumped. Has left me curious now, looked about here and elsewhere and couldn't find much, anything seemed similar to what I've tried there but they don't make a difference.

I want to try and create/find some form of Error Handling for this situation, similar to registering, either not proceeding with sending to the server if left blank or display a message.

This is the main part of the error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Address1', table 'C:\USERS\xxxx\PROJ (2)\PROJ\APP_DATA\ORDERS.MDF.dbo.Customer'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.]
```

Something simple I'm missing? Was considering the option of creating text boxes instead and connecting to the database individually, but that's a completely different route to this and there is quite nice, simple customizable options with the DetailsView.

Answer (score 0):

Well...typical after spending weeks confused by this one I managed to get it just after posting the question.

For anyone interested in this I used the 'If e.Exception Is Nothing Then' statement within the code similar to the two bottom examples I tried, THEN, used a Try/Catch statement.

Comment: Issue with this:  e.Exception is not a valid property for DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs.  It is for DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs (note difference between "Update" and "Updated").  So maybe the solution involved a different event?